# Xcode CGRectZero Error

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-graphics

I am getting the following error when compiling my code

```
      "_CGRectZero", referenced from:
          _CGRectZero$non_lazy_ptr in RootViewController.o
          _CGRectZero$non_lazy_ptr in SecondViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Build failed (1 error)

could someone tell me a solution to solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like your project is missing a framework.

Right-click on the *Frameworks* folder in your project's **Groups & Files** column, then select *Add* > *Existing Frameworks...*

Choose *CoreGraphics.framework* from the frameworks list.

Once you rebuild, this error should go away (unless it is something else).